# Why do deleted questions still show up in the anonymous feedback section?

Tags: support, 10k-tools, anonymous-visitors

For example, a post has a `9/-50` anonymous feedback, and shows up in the "overrated" section of Anonymous Post Feedback.

The question is closed and deleted.

The question deemed overrated was actually handled at some point, therefore that feedback was actioned and validated.

What's the rationale of still showing it in the anonymous feedback list? What other insights are there to be garnered?